# How to organize Drupal templates?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I created a few custom templates while modifying a theme (Acquia Prosper), and my usual practice is to put all my templates in this fashion:

> theme-name/templates/page/page-front.tpl.php

But it didn't quite work this time. So I'm wondering why. I looked through the templates.php for a clue, but there is nothing there. My base theme where I used this organization was genesis, and in that theme it seems to work, but not in Acquia Prosper.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a page.tpl.php in your subtheme?

Comment: yes, i do. Here is the interesting thing. Acquia Drupal doesn't allow subtheming (they say it breaks something or other), so there is only one theme, and no subtheme.

Answer (score 0):

page.tpl.php needs to be in the root of the theme, not in a subdirectory. Once you have created the template file, make sure you refresh the theme cache so that the file is added to the theme registry.

Devel, the theme developer module, and admin menu are really handy for theme development, so install those if you haven't already.